# App state change after login but before loading user info from firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, provider

I'm using firebase as my backend and each user has a `userData` document. After the user logs in fire firebase Auth another query is sent to the server to get the user's info and fetch his home feed, however after logging in the app state changes and the home feed is displayed before the query of getting the user's info is completed, and I'm stuck with an exception that some variables are null because I couldn't get them in time.
I'm using a `streamProvider` on `_firebaseAuth.authStateChanges()` to check if the user is logged in or not.
this is the code I use to authenticate users, and language is the necessary variable needed to know what documents to fetch on the home screen.

```
UserCredential userCredential = await _firebaseAuth
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
User user = userCredential.user;
DocumentSnapshot snapshot =
          await DatabaseServices().getUserData(user.uid);
await UserPreferences()
          .setUser(snapshot['username'], email, snapshot['language']);
```

I'm using `SharedPreferences` to store user's data, thought I'd mention.

And lastly this is my provider code

```
Provider<Authentication>(
  create: (_) => Authentication(FirebaseAuth.instance),
),
StreamProvider(
  create: (context) => context.read<Authentication>().authStateChanges,
  initialData: null,
),
```

```
final firebaseUser = context.watch<User>();
if (firebaseUser != null) {
  return Home();
}
return LoginPage();
```

this is the code my home feed

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:you/Firebase/databaseServices.dart';
import 'package:you/Notifiers/HomePostNotifier.dart';

import '../CustomWidgets/PostWidget.dart';

class Feed extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FeedState createState() => _FeedState();
}

class _FeedState extends State<Feed> {
  ScrollController _scrollController = new ScrollController();
  final int _pageLimit = 10;
  bool hasMore = true;
  bool isLoading = false;

  Future getFeed(HomePostNotifier feedNotifier) async {
    hasMore = true;
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String language = prefs.getString('language');
    await DatabaseServices().getHomeFeed(feedNotifier, language, _pageLimit);
  }

  Future loadMorePosts(HomePostNotifier notifier) async {
    if (!hasMore) {
      return;
    }
    if (isLoading) {
      return;
    }
    isLoading = true;
    int size = await DatabaseServices().getMorePosts(notifier, _pageLimit);
    if (size < _pageLimit) {
      hasMore = false;
    }
    isLoading = false;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    HomePostNotifier feedNotifier =
        Provider.of<HomePostNotifier>(context, listen: false);
    getFeed(feedNotifier);
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      double maxScroll = _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
      double currentScroll = _scrollController.position.pixels;
      double delta = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25;

      if (maxScroll - currentScroll <= delta) {
        loadMorePosts(feedNotifier);
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    HomePostNotifier feedNotifier = Provider.of<HomePostNotifier>(context);

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(250, 250, 250, 1),
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        backwardsCompatibility: false,
        systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
          statusBarColor: Colors.blue,
          statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
          systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.white,
          systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
        ),
        title: Text(
          'You',
          style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: GoogleFonts.pinyonScript().fontFamily,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 28),
        ),
      ),
      body: feedNotifier.homePostList.isEmpty
          ? Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              color: Colors.blue,
            ))
          : RefreshIndicator(
              onRefresh: () => getFeed(feedNotifier),
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              child: feedNotifier.homePostList.length == 0
                  ? SingleChildScrollView(
                      physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      child: Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
                            AppBar().preferredSize.height -
                            kBottomNavigationBarHeight * 2,
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Text(
                          "No posts yet. \nBe the first to break the ice :)",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 22,
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  : ListView.builder(
                      controller: _scrollController,
                      key: const PageStorageKey<String>('Home feed indicator'),
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return PostWidget(
                            index: index,
                            content: feedNotifier.homePostList[index].content,
                            username: feedNotifier.homePostList[index].username,
                            areCommentsAllowed: feedNotifier
                                .homePostList[index].areCommentsAllowed);
                      },
                      itemCount: feedNotifier.homePostList.length,
                    ),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

no value is being returned from `prefs.getSring()` when the user first signs in as I mentioned above, the value of language comes from firestore.
If anyone has any suggestion on how to fix it I would greatly appreciate it, thanks in advance.

Comment: Include the code for the `Home` widget, since the error is coming from there.

Comment: Added the code just like you mentioned

Comment: Please include the full code of the screen.

Comment: Here you go! the code works fine like i said the problem only occurs right after signing in or signing up, if a user signs in and close the app then reopen it, it works fine, even if he wants to refresh right after the exception. The language variable is set in shared preferences after successful login but not in time for the first time the home feed is fetched

Comment: Okay, so which variables are null when the error occurs?

Comment: email, language and username, the `UserPreferences()` method is a Shared Preferences method to save user info, I call it right after login and sign up. Those 3 variables should come from firestore from a query executed after login. since FirebaseAuth and Firestore are 2 separate things i have to make 1 query for each, and this is the problem is that Home feed gets called before the second query is finished hence why the variables are empty on first launch